# CSS3 push move div with respect to other div moving

Tags: jquery, html, css

Check out this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Renison/xhu6x5ub/) . I want to push the other div that has "Push this!" when the menu resizes/expands on hover. Is this possible entirely with css?

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><span>01</span> HomePage</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>02</span> SubPage 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>03</span> SubPage 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>04</span> SubPage 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>05</span> SubPage 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<div id="pad">push this!</div>
```

Comment: 1) The other div isn't in the jsfiddle,
2) What do you mean by push it? if you want to animate it using css - you can create a :hover selector and change the css of #pad

Comment: Sorry@NurBar it is in now. I want it to move away wrt the expanding menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `#nav`'s style from `position: absolute` to `float: left`.  Otherwise, `#nav` is taken outside the document flow and cannot affect the positioning of other elements.

Once you've done that, you can remove `padding-left` from `#pad`:

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/265713w1/)

---

You can get the same effect without using jQuery.  Add this CSS:

```
#nav {
  width:35px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

#nav:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/265713w1/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it with jQuery like you are in the jsFiddle, then consider:

```
$(function () {
$('#nav').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '200px'
    }, 500);
    $('#pad').animate({'padding-left':'200px'},500);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '35px'
    }, 500);
    $('#pad').animate({'padding-left':'35px'},500);
}).trigger('mouseleave');
```

});